# Urlpattern regular expression not working

Tags: django, regex, pattern-matching, django-urls

So i'm trying to make url like so

```
re_path(r'^product_list/(?P<category_slug>[\w-]+)/(?:(?P<filters>[\w~@=]+)?)$', views.ProductListView.as_view(), name='filtered_product_list'),
```

and at this point it works with things like:

/product_list/sdasdadsad231/bruh=1~3~10@nobruh=1~4

bruh=1~3~10@nobruh=1~4 - those are filters

but later i want to implement search by word functionality

so i want it recognize things like

/product_list/sdasdadsad231/?filters=bruh-1~3~10&nobruh-1~4&search_for=athing

/product_list/sdasdadsad231/?filters=bruh-1~3~10&nobruh-1~4

/product_list/sdasdadsad231/?search_for=athing

/product_list/sdasdadsad231/

so in different situations it will get filters and/or search_for or nothing at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might write the pattern as:

```
^product_list/(?P<category_slug>[\w-]+)/(?:\??(?P<filters>[\w~@=&-]+)?)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JI8KmS/1)

If you want to match the leading `/` from the example data, you can append that in the pattern after the `^`

Answer (score 0):

The part after the question mark is the [*query string* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) and does *not* belong to the path. Django will construct a `QueryDict` for this, and this will be available through [**`request.GET`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET). Indeed, if the path is for example:

```
/product_list/sdasdadsad231/?filters=bruh-1~3~10&nobruh-1~4&search_for=athing
```

Then the `?filters=bruh-1~3~10&nobruh-1~4&search_for=athing` is *not* part of the path, and it will be wrapped in `request.GET` as a `QueryDict` that looks like:

```
>>> QueryDict('filters=bruh-1~3~10&nobruh-1~4&search_for=athing')
<QueryDict: {'filters': ['bruh-1~3~10'], 'nobruh-1~4': [''], 'search_for': ['athing']}>
```

You thus can not capture the part after (and including) the question mark, this is already stripped of the path when trying to match with the `re_path(…)` and `path(…)` definitions.